# Empirical research into sectoral comovement

Tags: macroeconomics, empirical-evidence, business-cycles

I'm looking for some empirical studies into sectoral comovement. In particular, I'm interested in how manufacturing and services industries move together both in the long run and over the course of a business cycle. Most importantly, I'd like to know more about how the performance of manufacturing affects the performance of services. Are there any papers on this topic that you'd recommend?

So far I've only found a few papers which study sectoral comovement in more general terms and a few which only touched on this topic very briefly as an aside.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A relevant paper could be:

Veldkamp, Laura & Wolfers, Justin, 2007. "Aggregate shocks or aggregate information? Costly information and business cycle comovement," Journal of Monetary Economics, Elsevier, vol. 54(Supplemen), pages 37-55, September.

NBER Working Paper version: https://www.nber.org/papers/w12557

Published version: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304393207000529

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to move away from the general, and don't mind expanding your scope to resource extraction's impacts on other sectors, there's a lot of active literature on local labor markets.  For example, this paper and many of its references:

Marchand, Joseph, 2012. ["Local labor market impacts of energy boom-bust-boom in Western Canada"](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeejuecon/v_3a71_3ay_3a2012_3ai_3a1_3ap_3a165-174.htm) Journal of Urban Economics, 2012, vol. 71, issue 1, 165-174.